# How to replace values in a list at indexed positions?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have following list of text positions with all values being set to '-999' as default:

```
    List = [(70, 55), (170, 55), (270, 55), (370, 55),
            (70, 85), (170, 85), (270, 85), (370, 85)]

    for val in List:
        self.depth = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, value='-999', pos=val, size=(60,25))
```

I have indexed list and corresponding values at them such as:

```
    indx = ['2','3']
    val  = ['3.10','4.21']
```

I want to replace index locations '2' and '3' with values '3.10' and '4.21' respectively in 'List' and keep the rest as '-999'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used following example:

```
>>> s, l, m
([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 3, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> d = dict(zip(l, m))
>>> d  #dict is better then using two list i think
{0: 0, 1: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}
>>> [d.get(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(s)]
[0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

from [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231204/how-to-replace-values-at-specific-indexes-of-a-python-list)