# Replacing the elements in list at the positions given in replacement indices with new value in Python

Tags: python

I want to replace the elements in list at the positions given in replacement indices with new value. For example, if the given list is `replace_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[0,4,3],0)` then the outcome should be  `[0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8]`. I tried several approaches but none of them seems to work. I tried following code:

```
for i in new_value:
   list_a[i] = replacement_indices
return new_value
```

Comment: Related: [How to replace values at specific indexes of a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231204/how-to-replace-values-at-specific-indexes-of-a-python-list)

Comment: @jpp more like a duplicate right? you can close I'm not going to yell

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Slightly different IMO because that post supports different values for each index. While this doesn't matter for `list`, it may matter for NumPy (for example). Not that I'm suggesting we offer a NumPy solution here :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: a list comprehension approach which doesn't work in-place:

just decide between replacement value or original within a ternary expression based on the index in a list comprehension:

```
def replace_elements(inlist, indexes, replvalue):
    return [replvalue if i in indexes else x for i,x in enumerate(inlist)]

print(replace_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[0,4,3],0))
```

result:

```
[0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
```

for big index lists, `[0,4,3]` should be a `set` (`{0,4,3}`) for faster lookup.

Comment: The last line is pretty important here!

Comment: that said, a simple in-place loop doesn't need `set`.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting `replacment_indices` and `new_value` in the wrong places. You should iterate through `replacement_indices` and assign `new_value` to the list at each specified index instead:

```
for i in replacement_indices:
   list_a[i] = new_value
```

There's also no need to return anything since you're modifying the list in-place, which means that after the loop `list_a` would be modified per specifications already.

Comment: `return new_value` is the culprit. this code works in place

Comment: this is less showoff than mine because it doesn't use `set` but seems to be the most logical