# Substituting the values from list of lists by the values of another list based on indices in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Given lists are as follows:

```
mainList = [[0, 2, 1, 4, 3],
       [0, 2, 1, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 1, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2 ,3, 4],
       [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]]
```

and `list_indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],  list_value = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9]`.

The required list of lists is as follows:

```
mainList_mapped = [[0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4],
               [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9]]
```

Values of the mainList will be considered as indices and be replaced by the corresponding indices values in list_value. I tried but the code didn't work.

```
mainList_mapped = []

for ls in mainList:
    for (i, j) in zip(ls, list_value):
        ls[i] = j
    
    mainList_mapped.append(ls)
```

A similar answer is here [How to replace values at specific indexes of a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231204/how-to-replace-values-at-specific-indexes-of-a-python-list) but I'm getting Error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float) in getting my results. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like this:

```
mainList_mapped = []
for row in mainList:
    row_mapped = []
    for index in row:
        row_mapped.append(list_value[index])
    mainList_mapped.append(row_mapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that rearranges a list based on given indices:

```
def rearrange(value, indices):
    return [value[i] for i in indices]
```

Now apply this function to all the lists in the mainlist:

```
>>> result = [rearrange(list_value, indices) for indices in mainList]
>>> result
[[0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4],
 [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9],
 [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
 [0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.9],
 [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
 [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9],
 [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9]]
```

In this case it was easier because `list_indices` are sorted, but if it were shuffled, you could change the rearrange function like this:

```
mapping = dict(zip(list_indices, list_value))

def rearrange(mapping, indices):
    return [mapping[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a nested list comprehension:

```
print([[list_value[x] for x in i] for i in mainList])
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4], [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9], [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9], [0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.9], [0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9], [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9], [0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9]]
```